# Google Sheets Pivot table disappearing when entering new data

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I created a pivot table in Google Sheets that pulls student enrollment and attendance information from a report that we download from the state reporting system. I run this report multiple times a year to look at a variety of information. The columns always stay the same, but the rows/cell values change each time I run the report. When I paste the data over the data that I used last time, the pivot table goes blank. There is no easy way to identify what data has changed and the report contains thousands of rows of data. I tried re-selecting the pivot table data range, but the pivot table is still showing as blank. Is there a way to update the data without having to rebuild the pivot table in Google Sheets? I can't share the sheet I am working with since it contains confidential information.

Comment: Could you please share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet, free of sensitive information?

Comment: There is way too much info that I would have to remove. I created a very scaled back version with two tabs of sample data and a version of the pivot table I am working with. The actual sheets I am working with have upwards of 200 rows and about 50 columns. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DihQWnWnM-RTPc1VwXqP9BRDISdaSplLRO9_s0he1QE/edit?usp=sharing